# Parse binary file in C, how to count lines?

Tags: c, compression, binaryfiles

I have a text file, every two lines compose a component. For example:

```
name1
content1
name2
content2
....
```

To compress my file size, I convert a digital number of my content to 8-bit character. For example, the original text of the first component is:

```
Milk
price: 65
```

Then I compress the text to:

```
Milk
price: A
```

'A' is a ASCII character, and it's equal to 64 when convert into decimal. So I can save one byte from 65 to A. However, when I read the compressed file, I have a problem:

When I read the original text file, I can handle every component every two lines. That is, when I read the first two lines and find two '\n', I know this is the first component. When I read the second two lines and find two '\n', I know this is the second component. However, when I read the compressed file, a digital number my convert to a '\n' ASCII character, so I can't separate each component by two '\n'. So, what should I do? Any reply will be much appreciated!

Comment: If you are only replacing `65` with `A` how can the `\n` be affected in the compressed file? Another thought, if you have price: 650 what is your plan?

Comment: You should not convert or you should escape. Does this really provide any reasonable savings compared to the trouble it will bring?

Comment: @lU5er If the price is 650, I will convert 650 to 16bit binary number and then convert to two characters. Because the price is random, so if one price is 10, the ASCII character is LF(means a new line), so it will disturb me to separate each component by two lines.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen For example, the price is 65082, if I use char to save each number, I will need 5 characters. But if I convert 65082 to 16-bit binary number, then convert it to 2 characters, I just need 2 characters. The real problem maybe much more complicated. For example, the content is not the price but `120BCDCDABBAC`, there are 10 letters but only 4 kind after 120. So I can use  each two bit to represent a letter such as `00` to represent 'A', then I convert every 8 bit to a character, so I can save much more space

Comment: And when you add all the escaping, what percentage of the data is "compressable" by this, how much time is spent in implementing, compressing, decompressing... Sure you can do this, but using just an off-the-shelf general compression algorithm would get you better results with a lot less work.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen So, if I save the information use characters directly, then I use a compression software to compress it, I will get a much more better result? If I convert the char to binary then to character, then I use a compression software again, how about that?